Why does the .pt weight file size significantly decrease after training YOLOv8?
After training a YOLOv8 model, I noticed that the size of the .pt weight file significantly decreased compared to its initial size. What techniques are utilized in YOLOv8 that result in this reduction of file size? Additionally, does this size reduction affect the model's accuracy compared to its state before the reduction?

Please add the training command you used. I suppose, such parameters like image size, number of classes, and so on, affect the model size. Initial yolov8 pretrained models usually have image size 640 and 80 classes (trained on COCO dataset).

from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO(model="yolov8n-pose.pt")
model.train(data='/home/123/Desktop/ultralytics/ultralytics/cfg/datasets/pose2.yaml', epochs=400, imgsz=1920, batch=12, single_cls=True, rect=False, patience=800, resume=True, close_mosaic=10, save_period=5)

I tested it on a toy COCO8-Pose Dataset and was unable to reproduce the weights file size decreasing: the downloaded yolov8n-pose.pt is 6.51M, the last.pt and best.pt files size after training are 6.91M for img_size 1920 and 6.52M for img_size 640. In addition, I had to change the resume argument to False to start the training process (yolov8n-pose.pt training can not be resumed as it is already fully trained, you can start training the new model from this checkpoint). I would advise opening an issue on Ultralytics GitHub for your problem: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues

It's called model stripping.
It's done automatically after training stops.
But sometimes, if you force stop the training using ctrl+c, model stripping will not be performed.
In that case, you need to do it using this code manually:
from ultralytics.utils.torch_utils import strip_optimizer

strip_optimizer('best.pt')

What's the exact process behind it is unclear and maybe a team from ultralytics can better explain that.
